Firebase Appcheck not verifying token
I am creating an app where people can create docker containers. I am trying to protect my api by using firebase appcheck with reCAPTCHA enterprise. I have the frontend send a token to the backend for verification. I know the token is being sent, since I can console.log it when it gets to the backend so I am thinking it is an error with verification. The code doesn't show any errors, it just says Unauthorized. It doesn't have any errors it just won't authorize. Here is my code.
createcontainer.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Instance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
    <script type="module" src="check.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1>Create Gaming Instance</h1>
        <label for=""width>Width:</label>
        <input type="text" id="width" required><br><br>
        <label for="height">Height:</label>
        <input type="text" id="height" required><br><br>
        <label for="user">User:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" required><br><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" id="password" required><br><br>
        <button id="submitForm" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

script.js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.14.0/firebase-app.js";
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider, getToken } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.14.0/firebase-app-check.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "reyv-a8452.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "reyv-a8452",
    storageBucket: "reyv-a8452.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "174731893649",
    appId: "1:174731893649:web:685b864d27176334b4d830"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider("xxxxxxxxxx"),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true // Set to true to allow auto-refresh.
});

const submitForm = document.getElementById('submitForm');
submitForm.addEventListener("click", async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    let appCheckTokenResponse;
    appCheckTokenResponse = await getToken(appCheck, /* forceRefresh= */ false)

    // Send data to the backend
    fetch('/process', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Firebase-AppCheck': appCheckTokenResponse.token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ width: width, height: height, user: user, password: password })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Handle the response from the backend
        data = JSON.stringify({ data: data })
        data = data.replace('{"data":{"message":"', '')
        data = data.replace('"}}', '')
        window.location.href = data;
    })
})

server.js
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Docker = require('dockerode');
var docker = new Docker({host: 'xxxxxx', port: xxxxx});
var portnumber = "8080"
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./xxxxxxxxx");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  });

function createdockercontainer(width, height, portnumber, user, password) {
    docker.createContainer({Image: 'selkies', Tty: false, HostConfig: {ShmSize: 1073741824, NetworkMode: "host", Privileged: true}, Cmd: [width, height, portnumber, user, password]}, function(err,container){
        container.start();
    })
}

const incrementNr = (nr) => {
    const [nrDigits] = /\d*$/.exec(nr);
    const next = '' + (+nrDigits + 1);
    const nextNr = nr.slice(0, nr.length - Math.min(next.length, nrDigits.length)) + next;
    return nextNr;
  };

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const appCheckVerification = async (req, res, next) => {
  const appCheckToken = req.header('X-Firebase-AppCheck');
  console.log(appCheckToken)

  if (!appCheckToken) {
      res.status(401);
      return next("Unauthorized");
  }

  try {
      const appCheckClaims = await getAppCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);

      // If verifyToken() succeeds, continue with the next middleware
      // function in the stack.
      return next();
  } catch (err) {
      res.status(401);
      return next("Unauthorized");
  }
}

// Process the form data
app.post('/process', [appCheckVerification], (req, res) => {
    const width = req.body.width;
    const height = req.body.height;
    const user = req.body.user;
    const password = req.body.password;

    // Process the data or perform any backend tasks
    // ...

    // Return a response back to the frontend
    portnumber = incrementNr(portnumber)
    createdockercontainer(width, height, portnumber, user, password)
    res.json({
        message: 'https://reyv.org'
    });
});

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});

Not sure if this is related but when adding the reCAPTCHA enterprise key into the firebase console it shows a red ring. Firebase Console

What is getAppCheck() in server.js ?  And shouldn't you be passing the return value of admin.initializeApp() to it?

I figured out the problem. I changed the block of code that verifies to code from https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/10/protecting-backends-with-app-check/.
